# Insert a zero after every list elements

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
[-1. -1. -1. -1. -1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.  1.  1.  1.
 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]
```

and I'd like to insert a zero after each number:

```
[-1. 0. -1. 0. -1. 0. -1. 0. -1. 0.  1. 0. 1. 0.  1. 0. 1. (...) 0.]
```

My current attempt is:

```
S = np.zeros(P*len(bits))

S0=P/2*[A]+P/2*[-A] 
S1=P/2*[-A]+P/2*[A] 

for i in range(len(bits)):
    if bits[i]==0:
        S[i*P:(i+1)*P]= S0
    else:
        S[i*P:(i+1)*P]= S1
```

Comment: use commas between your list elements, not periods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have used a simple `zip` and list comprehension, like this

```
>>> data = [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1]
>>> [item for items in zip(data, [0] * len(data)) for item in items]
[-1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Or with the `itertools.chain`, `itertools.izip` and `itertools.repeat`

```
>>> from itertools import chain, izip, repeat
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(izip(data, repeat(0, len(data)))))
[-1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0]
```

The second one is very efficient, memory wise, if you are dealing with a very long list.

Comment: You can drop the `len(data)` from the itertools version; `izip` will stop as soon as `data` runs out.

Comment: @DSM Yeah, but I left it there so that people can follow the code without much explanation.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
In [6]: l = [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.]

In [7]: sum(([el, 0] for el in l), [])
Out[7]: [-1.0, 0, -1.0, 0, -1.0, 0, -1.0, 0, -1.0, 0, 1.0, 0, 1.0, 0]
```

Here, I've used `sum()` to concatenate `[-1., 0]`, `[-1., 0]` etc produced by the generator expression.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little bit different approach than the other answers. First make a generator:

```
def insert_every(L, char, every):
    '''generates items composed of L-items
    interweaved with char every-so-many items'''
    for i in range(len(L)):
        #all the items in `L` are yielded eventually
        yield L[i]
        #char is yielded next if the current L item number is divisible by `every`
        if (i+1) % every == 0:
            yield char
```

Then use it to spit out your new list:

```
newL = list(insert_every(oldL, 0, 1))
```

OR:

```
newL = [i for i in insert_every(oldL, 0, 1)]
```

This is flexible; you could also use it to spit out a `dict` or `tuple`:

```
tup = tuple(insert_every(oldL, 0, 1))
dic = {i:i for i in insert_every(oldL, 0, 1)} #kind of useless but you get the idea
```

I feel like doing it this way is a little bit more explicit as to what you are doing, as well as more flexible and reusable for later, and very memory-friendly. Plus you get to use generators, which are always a hoot.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a list comprehension:

```
lst = [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1,
        1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,]

lst = [0 if i % 2 else e for i,e in enumerate(lst)]

print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[-1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
  0, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a=[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1]
>>> list(itertools.chain(*([x,0] for x in a)))
[-1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0]
```

from basic approach:

```
>>> my_list = []
>>> for x in a:
...     my_list.append(x)
...     my_list.append(0)
... 
>>> my_list
[-1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0]
```